# Content Type Hub in SharepointOnline(Office35)

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type-hub

In on-premise sharepoint we create a site-collection which will function as as Content Type Hub. I read in one of the forums that Sharepoint Online has a default Content Type Hub. But when I go to the site-collections listing I can't see there.

Can somebody share the location of Content Type Hub in sharepoint online?

Answer (score 2):

The Content Type Hub will not be visible in the sitecollection listing. But however you can access it from `https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/contentTypeHub`

Answer (score 1):

it is not visible but default content type is their and can be access via site collection named `/sites/contentTypeHub`.

But here is one issue. only the original Office 365 account creator has access to the site collection.  Accessing it with another user will get you an access denied error message even if you are a global administrator.

**fix:** Unfortunately, you cannot fix this yourself from the tenant administration page because this site collection does not show up on the list.  This means you need to get the person who created the original Office 365 account to go to this site collection and add you as a site collection administrator.  It’s easy to fix but it requires you to involve whomever set up the account to begin with.

http://dotnetmafia.sys-con.com/node/2172946/mobile

Answer (score 0):

You could link to "content type hub site", from site settings. Please, follow this blog images (site is on spanish).

http://sharepointforthewin.com/2016/05/25/contenttype-hubs-o365/